# Как в батнике прописать выполнение команд после подключения по SSH?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, bat

Подключаюсь таким батником через cmd к Ubuntu по SSH

```
ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Как мне в него добавить команды, которые должны выполнятся после входа? Например, такие:

```
sudo apt-get update && echo Y|sudo apt-get install screen && итд...
```

Comment: Да вроде бы как обычно, в конце командной строки, заключив конвейер команд в кавычки: **"sudo apt-get update && echo Y|sudo apt-get install screen"**. Вот только после исполнения команд соединение будет прекращено.

Comment: @Daemon-5, у apt/apt-get/aptitude есть опция `-y`

Answer (score 0):

Нужен [ключ](https://habr.com/ru/post/122445/) `-t`.

```bsh
ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -t touch /tmp/blablalba
```